# Draw a line to nearest marker on click in R Leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, gis

I am a new leaflet user in R trying to add some custom options. In my map I have markers for certain treatment locations in one control group and a different type of treatment center as circlemarkers in another control group. What I would like to do is that, upon a user clicking a marker, a line would appear to the nearest coordinate which is known and in the dataframe. Then, if the user clicks a different marker, the original line would be removed and a new one drawn. Additionally, if the user removes the relevant control group, any lines and the clicking function would stop. From reading forums it seems like this should be possible but my knowledge of javascript is very limited. Here is a really simplified example:

```
df = data.frame(Lat1 = c(38.703,38.221,41.837),
                Long1 = c(-90.330,-85.737,-87.605),
                Lat2 = c(38.221,41.837,38.703),
                Long2 = c(-85.737,-85.737,38.221))

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(data = df %>% slice(1:2), group = "1", lat = ~Lat1, lng = ~Long1) %>%
  addMarkers(data = df %>% slice(3), group = "2", lat = ~Lat1, lng = ~Long1) %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("1","2"), options= layersControlOptions(collapsed=F))
```

[image]

Here, if a user clicks on a marker, a line would be drawn between the clicked marker and the known nearest coordinate (lat2/long2, these may not actually be closest, but its just for proof of concept). Then, if a different marker is selected, the previous line would be removed and the new line added. Finally, if control group 1 is deselected, all lines and this functionality are removed but remain if 2 is deselected. I also have base group layers not represented in this example but I don't think that's relevant here. Based on my reading this may not be possible in base R leaflet without use of the htmlwidgets::onRender function, but even if a javascript user could show me how this might work in JS it might help me convert it to R. Thank you for your help.